# How can I get magnetometer values with xamarin using the Device Motion Plugin?

Tags: c#, cross-platform, xamarin.forms, devicemotion

I try to get the magnetic field data for a crossplateform application developped by xamarin. I am quite beginner with mobile developpement especially Xamarin. 
So I have the Hello Word code:

```
public App ()
        {
            // The root page of your application
                MainPage = new ContentPage {

            Content = new StackLayout {           
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {

                          XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                         Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                        }
                    }
                }

            }; 


        }
```

And I want to display 3 coordinate values of the magnetometre in the first page.

Device Motion Plugin is a multiplateform plugin, I have also this code but I don't know how to do to display these values in the application.

```
        CrossDeviceMotion.Current.Start(MotionSensorType.Magnetometer);
        CrossDeviceMotion.Current.SensorValueChanged += (s, a) =>
        {

            switch (a.SensorType)
            {

                case MotionSensorType.Magnetometer:
                    Debug.WriteLine("A: {0},{1},{2}", ((MotionVector)a.Value).X, ((MotionVector)a.Value).Y, ((MotionVector)a.Value).Z);

                    break;

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you need to set the `x:Name` attribute of your label. I have been using the accelerometer, so my name is `accelerometerLog`.

Then from your code you can do the following:

```
accelerometerLog.Text = String.Format(
    "X:{0} Y:{1} Z:{2}", 
    ((MotionVector)a.Value).X, 
    ((MotionVector)a.Value).Y, 
    ((MotionVector)a.Value).Z
);
```